# remove transparent of imageresource in floating action button

Tags: android

i have set a floating action button background as translucent but when i set image resource it happen to be translucent too how can i remove translucent in an image
resource in floating action button

xml codes.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fabwallaper"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="16dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

java code.

```
        actionButton=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabwallaper);
    actionButton.setAlpha(0.25f);
    actionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_terrain_white);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set image from **XML** file. Try this one `android:src="@drawable/your_image_res"` and
change `android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"` **to** `app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"`.

Look at that difference:

**android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"**

[image]

**app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the button as translucent. Try using the alpha percentage with the backgroundTint color, so you'd set

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorWithAlphaLevel"
```

And your ImageResource would not be affected.

To set apha do a color, just add 1 byte to your original color, for example:

`#000000` represents a full black, adding 1 more byte it would be `#FF000000`

For 25% alpha you would need `#40000000`

Comment: this one worked but it show like there are two borders in which the inner one does not have a background color and the outer one has the translucent color which we have set